# Node js : Best way to define entity class

Tags: node.js, entity-framework

I am writing one tool in node js. I wanted to define some POJO in node js. I don't have much experience in Node js. I came from JAVA background where classes are used for defining entities. One way, in which I have define entities now are:-

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.values = [];
    this.characteristics = {};
}
```

But this is defined in one JS file. And to make it available in other JS files, I have to export this function. Is this the best way to define entities or are there any other way in which I can define something of class kind of format?

Comment: Try modelar, it uses class to define model. http://modelar.hyurl.com. The way you define a Person is old style, please try class whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is just fine for creating objects.  If you start to use a DB like mongo, you might be better off creating objects with mongoose but that's personal preference as well.  As for your example -

1) Export Person

```
module.exports = Person;
```

2) Import Person from another file

```
const Person = require('../path/to/Person');
```

3) Create Person with the `new` keyword to call the constructor (very important)

```
const mitch = new Person('Mitch');
```

You should read up on `javascript's prototype`.  Every object has a reference to `Object.prototype`.  Then you can create objects with `Object.create(obj)` to create objects and assign the new object's prototype as the reference being passed in to `Object.create(obj)`

[Here's an example from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)

```
// Shape - superclass
function Shape() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
}

// superclass method
Shape.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
  this.x += x;
  this.y += y;
  console.info('Shape moved.');
};

// Rectangle - subclass
function Rectangle() {
  Shape.call(this); // call super constructor.
}

// subclass extends superclass
Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle;

var rect = new Rectangle();

console.log('Is rect an instance of Rectangle?',
  rect instanceof Rectangle); // true
console.log('Is rect an instance of Shape?',
  rect instanceof Shape); // true
rect.move(1, 1); // Outputs, 'Shape moved.'
```